# What is the fastest way to pass database cell values to many different PHP variables?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database which serves as an array of ~70 values. I am trying to find the most efficient code to pass each cell value to a variable, preferebly coded in PHP.

Example:

```
Cell1   Cell2 Cell3 Cell4 ... Cell70
```

Pass each cell 1-70 to a variable named after that cell:

```
($CELL1, $CELL2, $CELL3, $CELL4 ... $CELL70)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this as opposed to just having a single variable that's an array?

Comment: I should have specified: these variables are individual metrics that I need to post throughout my website, so a single variable wouldn't work in this case. I'll update OP.

Comment: Why not?  What's the difference between using `$array["Cell1"]` and `$Cell1`?

Comment: Because I didn't know I could do that xD Thanks a lot, @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be FAR simpler to just use an array:

```
$arr = oci_fetch_array(...);
```

so you don't pollute the namespace with a bunch of (mostly) useless variables.

If you INSIST on going this route, then you could try:

```
list($cell1, $cell2, $cell3, ...., $cellWayTooManyCells) = oci_fetch_array(...);
```

Or

```
$arr = oci_fetch_assoc(...);
extract($arr);
```

Comment: I understand using an array would work better, but then how would I call each value individually, seeing as I need them on different pages throughout the website? Thanks a lot for the answer though! It's extremely helpful.

Comment: "different pages"? as in different PHP scripts building multiple pages? You shouldn't be fetching fields/values you aren't going to be using. e.g. `select field_you_need_to_use from ...` instead of `select *`. `select *` when you only use a couple fields is like going to the grossery store, buying the ENTIRE inventory, driving it all home, then throwing all but the candy bar you wanted into the trash.

Comment: My idea, which may be dumb now that you all have answered my q, originally was to make a variables.php file which would I would require on pages that I need. From there I could call the variable. Your way is much more simple, thanks! I'm obviously new to PHP/HTML. Only a week in lol.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of no practical reason to use multiple variables over an array, but you could in theory use variable variables:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    ${"Cell" + $i} = $arr[$i];
}
```

Instead it would be much simpler to just use `$arr["Cell1"]` in spots where you may want to use `$Cell1`.